# Как сделать общий метод двум классам C#

Tags: c#, ооп

У нас есть общий метод

```
FindPerimetr()
```

для классов 
`Rectangle` и `Square`.
Как реализовать так чтобы не писать метод два раза в разных классах? Слышал что то про родительский класс это оно?

Comment: унаследуйте `Square` oт `Rectangle`

Comment: @Igor Барбара Лисков будет недовольна!

Comment: Если можно код скиньте)

Comment: Вариант простой - static метод можно изпользовать из разных классов. Вариант 2 посложнее - сделать третий класс, который наследуют два предыдущих. Вариант 3. Используйте static Template метод. Вариант 4 "нечесный" используйте рефлексию (System.Reflection). Возможны "комбинации"

Comment: У меня нет кода. Тем более - Барбара.

Comment: @PashaPash, тогда Rectange от Square? :-)

Comment: Если уж так не хочется писать 2 раза, то для данной задачи можно использовать формулу P=2(a+b) и для квадрата.  Тогда в ответе @PashaPash в классе Polygon можно будет реализовать метод из класса Rectangle  и использовать только его. Ну и вывести в Polygon   и свойства. И вообще Вам тогда отдельный класс для квадрата не нужен :)

Comment: @PashaPash если класс иммутабельный, то Square oт Rectangle Барбара наследовать разрешает. Тут скорее проблемы с неоптимильностью вылезают...

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, согласен. наиболее близкий к желанию автора, кстати, вариант от Alex Petrachuk - там и классы (потенциально) мутабельные, и метод подсчета периметра написан ровно один раз, в общем виде

Comment: @PashaPash так у него же тоже LSP нарушен

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, но это легко починить, сделав точки приватными

Answer (score 9):

К сожалению, вам придется реализовать этог метод дважды, т.к. его реализация отличается для квадрата и для прямоугольника.

```
public abstract class Polygon
{
    public abstract double FindPerimetr();
}

public class Square : Polygon
{
    public double Size { get; set; }

    public override double FindPerimetr()
    {
        return Size * 4;
    }
}

public class Rectangle : Polygon
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public override double FindPerimetr()
    {
        return (Width + Height) * 2;
    }
}
```

Вариант с интерфейсом вместо `abstract class` тоже подойдет.

Вам будут советовать унаследовать квадрат от прямоугольника - но такое наследование нарушит [принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2). А нарушать принципы из списка SOLID нехорошо. Например, вы скажете "квадрат - это такой прямоугольник, у которого ширина равна высоте". И напишете вот такой код:

```
public class Square : Rectangle
{
    public override double Width { get => base.Width; set => base.Width = base.Height = value; }
    public override double Height { get => base.Height; set => Width = value; }
}

public class Rectangle
{
    public virtual double Width { get; set; }
    public virtual double Height { get; set; }

    public double FindPerimetr()
    {
        return (Width + Height) * 2;
    }
}
```

Плохой препод по ООП скажет "молодец, ты проявил знание наследования!". Хороший препод по ООП скажет: Смотри, у нас был вот такой метод `Stretch(Rectangle r)`, который растягивал прямоугольник в 2 раза:

```
static void Stretch(Rectangle r)
{
    r.Height *= 2;
    r.Width *= 2;
}
```

И этот метод отлично работает до тех пор, пока не в него не попадет квадрат. А квадрат он, внезапно, сделает длинее и шире в 4 раза.

Comment: Ну есть "нечесный" вариант - через рефлексию опросить все свойства и просумировать.

Comment: А если завести класс Прямоугольник со свойствами X и Y, от него наследовать класс квадрата, но определить `prop Y => X`?

Comment: @Андрей как раз дописал

Comment: @PashaPash, простите, но `r.Height *= 2; r.Width *= 2;` также учетверит и прямоугольник

Comment: @Андрей оно сделает его в два раза длинее и два раза шире. А квадрат - в 4 длинее и в 4 раза шире :)

Comment: @Андрей убрал сомнительное слово

Comment: @Андрей это, кстати, стандартный пример с  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle - "A typical example that violates LSP is a Square class that derives from a Rectangle class..."

Comment: @nick_n_a стремный вариант, только если хочется удивить того, кто будет читать код :)

Comment: Вы написали так что если бы мы каждому отдельно прописали бы метод было бы лучше и меньше кода

Comment: @Denver так в том и идея. Зато с таким довесом вы можете написать метод, который будет подсчитывать периметр сразу пачки квадратов и треугольников, лежащих в одном массиве `Polygon[]`.

Comment: @PashaPash , кажется я понял) А лучше второй вариант использовать?

Comment: @Denver второй вариант вообще нельзя использовать. Т.е. можно только в случае, если это учебное задание, вы проходите тему "наследование" и имя Лисков на паре не звучало. Во всех остальных случаях - первый вариант единственный верный.

Comment: @PashaPash, А с помощью посетителя данный функционал как можно реализовать?

Comment: @Андрей можно с помощью чего угодно - но код вычисления все равно будет разный для разных фигур.

Answer (score 6):

Добавлю к ответу PashaPash еще два способа унаследовать квадрат от прямоугольника, которые не нарушают LSP.

Первый способ - можно сделать их неизменяемыми:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public double Width { get; }
    public double Height { get; }

    public Rectangle (double w, double h)
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
    }

    public double FindPerimetr() => (Width + Height) * 2;
}

public class Square : Rectangle 
{
    public Square (double size) : base(size, size) { }
}
```

Способ второй - оставить их изменяемыми, но не давать прямого контроля над значениями свойств:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public double Width { get; protected set; }
    public double Height { get; protected set; }

    public Rectangle (double w, double h)
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
    }

    public double FindPerimetr() => (Width + Height) * 2;

    public void Stretch(double s)
    {
        Width *= s;
        Height *= s;
    }
}

public class Square : Rectangle 
{
    public Square (double size) : base(size, size) { }
}
```

Но надо заметить, что второй пример на самом деле соблюдает LSP ценой жертвы OCP (принципа открытости-закрытости): любая операция, добавленная в базовый класс, должна учитывать все его подклассы, а неучтенные заранее подклассы оказываются при таком подходе запрещены.

К примеру, если бы в класс `Rectangle` был добавлен метод `void Stretch(double sx, double sy)` - то его наличие уже не позволило бы унаследовать класс `Square` от `Rectangle`.

Тем не менее, OCP не так важен как LSP - и при построении, к примеру, DSL (языков специфичных для предметной области) такой подход может быть оправдан.

Answer (score 1):

Для любой плоской фигуры из 4-х точек периметром будет сумма длин отрезков их соединяющих. Если расчет периметра реализовать в абстрактном классе - реализовывать в наследниках не потребуется.

```
using System;

namespace Perimeter
{
    public class Point
    {
        public double X { get; private set; }
        public double Y { get; private set; }

        public Point(double X, double Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Tetragon
    {
        public Point Vertex1 { get; private set; }
        public Point Vertex2 { get; private set; }
        public Point Vertex3 { get; private set; }
        public Point Vertex4 { get; private set; }

        public Tetragon(Point Vertex1, Point Vertex2, Point Vertex3, Point Vertex4)
        {
            this.Vertex1 = Vertex1;
            this.Vertex2 = Vertex2;
            this.Vertex3 = Vertex3;
            this.Vertex4 = Vertex4;
        }

        public double FindPerimetr()
        {
            double Length1 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Vertex2.X - Vertex1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(Vertex2.Y - Vertex1.Y, 2));
            double Length2 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Vertex3.X - Vertex2.X, 2) + Math.Pow(Vertex3.Y - Vertex2.Y, 2));
            double Length3 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Vertex4.X - Vertex3.X, 2) + Math.Pow(Vertex4.Y - Vertex3.Y, 2));
            double Length4 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Vertex1.X - Vertex4.X, 2) + Math.Pow(Vertex1.Y - Vertex4.Y, 2));

            return Length1 + Length2 + Length3 + Length4;
        }
    }

    public class Rectangle : Tetragon
    {
        public Rectangle(double width, double height)
            : base(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, height), new Point(width, height), new Point(width, 0))
        { }
    }

    public class Square : Tetragon
    {
        public Square(double size)
            : base(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, size), new Point(size, size), new Point(size, 0))
        { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // 10
            var rec = new Rectangle(2, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Perimeter of rectangle: {0}", rec.FindPerimetr()));

            // 4
            var square = new Square(1);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Perimeter of square: {0}", square.FindPerimetr()));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Отличный вариант! Можно еще попробовать вариант с передачей в базовый класс не точек, а массива длин сторон.

Comment: @PashaPash как минимум, этот вариант вносит погрешность при вычислении периметра прямоугольных фигур. Во-вторых, применительно к вопросу автора, жуткий оверинженеринг, базового Tetragon хватит за глаза. В-третьих, если это всё-таки Rectangle, а не TetragonPerimeter, то даже YAML не является оправданием, чтобы засовывать в него длины сторон, которые наследникам нафиг не сдались, а поддерживать их придётся всю жизнь.

Comment: @LunarWhisper я же написал выше - хранение длин сторон вместо точке отлично убирает погрешность. И нет, это не Rectangle, а именно  Tetragon - потому что в ООП квадрат - не прямоугольник (LSP). Ну и кто его знает, что там сдалось наследникам - пока их два, и длины сторон нужны обоим наследникам.

Comment: @LunarWhisper вообще тут скорее "какой вопрос - такой и ответ". Нельзя написать вычисление периметра один раз. Если написать его один раз - значит что-то другое придется написать / хранить два раза.

Comment: Плохой вариант. У любого квадрата после его создания можно взять и сдвинуть любую из вершин в любую сторону - то есть такой код не обеспечивает внутренние инварианты типов.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много. Незнаю нужно ли учить плохому , но я бы выделил:

1. "Дружбу классов".
2. Рефлексию.
3. Наследование. Можно обьявить в базовом классе функцию, и реализовать её в других классах (рекомендуеться)
4. Можно создать интерфейс "Периметр" и вычислять через наследование+интерфейс
5. В базовом классе можно создать массив "стороны", который заполнять при создании класса, в массив можно добавлять дубликаты полей для правильного счёта.

Покажу из них два.

1. "дружбу классов"

   ```
   public double FindPerimetr() {  
     if (this is Square) return ((Square)this).Size *4;
     if (this is Rectangle)
       return (((Rectangle)this).Width +    ((Rectangle)this).Height) * 2;
     return 0; // неизвесно что
   ```

   }

Недостаток, тот кто будет наследовать ваш класс - будет недоволен что его периметр не считается. Если "правильно" расставить if-последовательность и одинаково назвать одну из сторон - можно обойтись двумя классами.

2. Можно "схитрить" через рефлексию

   ```
   using System.Reflection;     // рефлексия
   using System.ComponentModel; // тут AmbientValue 
    public class Polygon {
   public double FindPerimetr() {
        double ret = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo item in this.GetType().GetProperties())
         if (item.PropertyType == typeof(double)) // Проверки
             ret += (double) item.GetValue(this,null);
         return ret;
         }
      }
   ```

Метод будет работать если каждая сторона "присутствует". Если нужно множители - их нужно где-то прописать, например в атрибутах.

Например так:

```
 public class Polygon {
  public double FindPerimetr() {
     double ret = 0;
     foreach (PropertyInfo item in this.GetType().GetProperties())
      if (item.PropertyType == typeof(double)) // Проверки 
          {
          object[] attr = item.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AmbientValueAttrubute,false);
          ret += ((double) item.GetValue(this,null)) 
            * ((attr.Length==0)?0: (double) ((AmbientValueAttrubute)attr[0]).Value);
          }
      return ret;
      }

   }
public class Rectangle : Polygon  {
  [AmbientValue(4)]
  public double Size { get; set;}
  }
```

Но лучше для атрибута создать свой класс на базе Attribute. 
Рефлексия не считается хорошим тоном, но как вариант. Она сложная, чуть замедляет работу и плохочитабельна. Про доп-атрибут тому кто будет продолжать дорабоатывать вашу библиотеку прийдётся тоже догадываться.

А вот стоит ли "овчина выделки" - судите сами.

Comment: судя по всему в дружбе классов приведение должно было быть к классу который проверяется в `is` а не к Rectangle

Comment: @Grundy да, упустил.

Comment: Если вы определяете `AmbientValue` специально для подсчёта периметра через рефлексию, почему бы не просто определить виртуальный метод `GetPerimeter`?

Comment: @Vlad что бы не реализовывать (писать) метод два раза, как написано в вопросе.

Comment: @nick_n_a: А, понял! Я недочитал условие, как оказалось :)